# JPA @PreUpdate for update query using entityManager.createNativeQuery()

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I have below base entity class which is extended by 2 JPA Entity class.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
     ...
     ...

     @PrePersist
     protected void onCreate() {
         this.modifiedOn = new Date();
     }

     @PreUpdate
     protected void onUpdate() {
        this.modifiedOn = new Date();
     }
}
```

Now if I update few columns using below native query call using entity manager. Will it call `@PreUpdate` ?

```
Query query = super.getEntityManager(Constant.PSUNIT).createNativeQuery("UPDATE CUSTOMER SET TYPE = 'XYZ' WHERE SOURCE = 'ABC'");
query.executeUpdate();



@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer extends CustomerSuper {
// customer related fields. and getting setter with annotations.
 ...
 ... 
 ...
}


@MappedSuperclass
public class CustomerSuper extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like it does not call preUpdate if the update is fired for native query though we are using entity manager.

May be the reason behind this is that the job of creating query is managed by our code instead of hibernate.